# CopperCube game engine Android export failed

Tags: android, export

I am using CopperCube 6.0.2 to develop my game.

I am able to export my game to exe and webgl format, but when I try to export it to .apk format it says:

> aapt tool .exe missing error

I downloaded the sdk pakage and it now shows:

> failed to find the android jar

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Did you follow all of the steps of [their documentation](http://ambiera.com/coppercube/doc/index.html) for [exporting to Android](http://ambiera.com/coppercube/doc/cnt_android_app.html)? Specifically, have you installed Java (JDK) & are you target the correct Android version?

Comment: thank you,yes i have downloaded the android studio the sdk manager is not working so i downloaded the 6.0 sdk manually but when i try to export my game it shows an error of missing files folder location etc etc.have you exported your game to android successfully?  if yes please provide the folder of the android sdk please [request].

Comment: and yes i have java installed wit sdk

Comment: I haven't used CopperCube myself. The errors you mentioned in your comment sound different than the ones in your question text. editing your question to include the exact error text that you're getting would make it easier for other to help you resolve the problem.